# `materialize mode required, but it is not allowed in this context` error in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, record, return-next, return-query

I created `my_func()` which returns `SETOF RECORD` type with a [RETURN NEXT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) or [RETURN QUERY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT) statement as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE 
  row RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN VALUES (ROW('John','Smith')), (ROW('David','Miller')) LOOP
    RETURN NEXT row;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES (ROW('John','Smith')), (ROW('David','Miller'));
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But, calling `my_func()` got the error as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func();
ERROR:  materialize mode required, but it is not allowed in this context
```

Actually, I tried both the examples above with `enable_material=on` and `enable_material=off` but the error was not solved:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('enable_material');
 current_setting
-----------------
 on
(1 row)
```

```
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('enable_material');
 current_setting
-----------------
 off
(1 row)
```

So, how can I solved the error?

In addition, I could successfully call `my_func()` below which returns `SETOF INT` type with a `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` statement:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF INT AS $$
DECLARE 
  num INT;
BEGIN
  FOR num IN VALUES (1), (2), (3) LOOP
    RETURN NEXT num;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS SETOF INT AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY VALUES (1), (2), (3);
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: The wording of the error message is a bit of "inside baseball".  Just consider it to mean "sorry, you can't do that" and use the workaround you already found.

Answer (score 0):

You must define what a `record` is. Either do it in the function (return table, or with `out` parameters) or at call time

```sql
select * from my_func() as (first_name text, last_name text);
```

Comment: I tried your code, then I got the error `ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type`.

Comment: remove the `row(..)`, just keep `RETURN QUERY VALUES ('John','Smith'),('David','Miller');`